# Theta (thetaEst) estimates in CatR with known item parameters - assessing a whole dataset

Tags: r, item-response-theory

To my R angels,

After a recent voyage of discovery, I have been using IRT to develop a set of GRM derived item parameters on a large dataset of 40000 questionnaire responses.

I would like to use these item parameters to estimate theta (ability) of the whole dataset. Thereafter, I would like to use the same parameters to estimate theta on a subset of items.

I've been trying to use the thetaEst function in CatR.

```
thetaEst(it, x)
```

Where "it" is a matrix of my item parameters. "x" is a vector of item responses.

As a vector, I can calculate a single participants theta estimate.

I would like to expand x from a single vector, to be able to input a matrix of 40000 responses.

I can't see how this is possible - any help would be very gratefully received.

Jon

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use the `mirt` package to fit the Graded Response Model? Then, you can use the `fscores()` function from the mirt package to extract the person parameters for all individuals.

Another option is the 1factor.scores()1 function from the `ltm` package after fitting the model using the `grm()` function.